# Unable to connect Filebeats with Elastic Cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, centos, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am facing an issue while connecting filebeats with my trial version of elastic cloud.

I am getting below error

```
ERROR pipeline/output.go:100  Failed to CLOUD_ID): 401 Unauthorized: 
 {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate user
 [USER_EMAIL] for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" 
charset=\"UTF-8\"","Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey"]}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":
"unable to authenticate user ...
```

I have attached my filebeat.yml too. Please look.
[image]
I crossed check my username and password both are correct.
please help!

Answer (score 0):

Here my cloud credentials don’t look right. The syntax for cloud.auth is user:password
It needs to be the cluster credentials, not the cloud account credentials. (Default username is elastic, and you’re presented a randomly generated password when the cluster is created)